# Get binary string from BINARY(180) in mysql

Tags: mysql, node.js

I have a column `X` of type `BINARY(170)` for `1360` bitmap and want a column `Y` with bitmap string like `'001101....'`
tried using `LPAD((CONV(HEX(X),16,2)),1360,'0') AS Y`
but since `CONV` works only till 64 bit number, this gives wrong answer.
How could I accomplish this in MySQL ?

Comment: Create service table with 1-byte chars and according binary representation. Convert each separate byte and aggregate into one string.

Comment: could you elaborate, what's a service table. I am not proficient in mysql so would be helpful if some code is provided

Comment: Service table is separate table which is created with auxiliary purposes. For your task this should be a table which contains 1-char column with bytes 0-255 and another column with their 8-char binary representation. This will improve the query. Of course, you may not create static table but generate this table dynamically in CTE.

Comment: Ok. got it. I am doing something similar in node, I am just iterating over the Buffer returned for X column, converting it to binary string and concat them in the end.